# Reduction between Parity-SAT and approximate counting

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, reductions, satisfiability, polynomial-time-reductions

Consider two problems as defined [here](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7Edanama/courses/adv-comp/scribe22.pdf).

**Approximate counting:** Given a Boolean function $f(x)$, for $x \in \{0, 1\}^{n}$, distinguish between the two cases:

1. The number of satisfying assignments for $f(x)$ is $\geq 2^{k+1}$.
2. The number of satisfying assignments for $f(x)$ is $\leq 2^{k}$.

We are promised that one of these cases is true. $k$ is some integer between $0$ and $n-1$.

**Parity-SAT:** Given a Boolean function $f(x)$, for $x \in \{0, 1\}^{n}$, output $1$ if the number of satisfying assignments to $f(x)$ is even.

Is there a way to reduce Parity-SAT to approximate counting (or vice versa)?

Comment: What's $k$?  Part of the input?  $n-1$?  Please make the problem self-contained.

Comment: I suggest you read about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PP_(complexity) vs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_P and read ahead in the notes.

Comment: I updated the question. The links you mention (or the lecture notes) do not contain a reduction

Comment: Suppose the number of solutions is greater than $2^{k}$ but less than $2^{k+1}$?  That would be a third case.

Comment: We are promised that we are only in case 1 or case 2.